# Vim, how to delete empty lines to "_ automatically?

Tags: vim

How can we let Vim always remove the content to `"_` when we are deleting empty lines with `*N*dd`, or `d*motion*`?

**EDIT1：**

For example, I've written *"Hello"* somewhere, and yank it with `yy`.
Then I move cursor to elsewhere, remove some blank lines by `N+dd` to "_ without explicitly indicating the register `"_`. , 
Then I can go a proper line to paste the *"Hello"* just with `p`.

**EDIT2：**

Can we **achieve this by letting vim check the deleted content and edit the registers accordingly** ?
( I'd like to modify the behavior of `N+dd` depending on the content I'm deleting.)

(Though mapping `leader-key d` to `"_d` works well, but when I'm working in this way I still have to tell myself: "Hey, you are deleting empty lines, and you should use special keys". )

Comment: Post specific inputs and desired outputs please

Comment: @KevinDTimm to "_ means: into the `black hole` register

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting idea. Basically, you would like to have a "clever" delete. This means you need to define a new operator.

How to define a new operator is described in the Vim help under [`:h :map-operator`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#%3amap-operator).

The code for a clever delete would include something like this:

```
nnoremap <silent> d :<C-U>set opfunc=CleverDelete<CR>g@
function! CleverDelete(type)
  let reg_save = @@
  if a:type ==# 'line'
    normal! '[V']ygv
    if @@ =~ '\%^\_s*\%$'
      normal! "_d
      let @@ = reg_save
    else
      normal! d
    endif
  elseif a:type ==# 'char'
    " ...
    " TODO
  else
    " TODO
  endif
endfunction
```

This works for linewise deletes: `dj` becomes `"_dj` if it would delete only whitespace.

Now you need to implement characterwise deletes, Visual mode mappings, `v:count` handling, linewise mappings `dd`, etc. This is just a start.

Answer (score 2):

From my `~/.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <leader>d "_d
vnoremap <leader>d "_d
```

Just replace the first `d` in `dd` with `<leader>d`. That's one less key.

Examples:

```
4,dd
,dt:
Vjj,d
```

Answer (score 1):

Remap `d` to `"_d` with the following commands:

```
nnoremap d "_d
vnoremap d "_d
```

This will remap the `d` for the normal and visual mode. Notice that if you have any other mappings or function that calls the `d`command, you will have to adjust, or it will call the default `d`, not the new `"_d`mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to use the `"0` register.  Things you yank are stored in there as well as the default register so you can use it to put after you've deleted lines.

So you'd do something like this:

```
yy  # Yank your line
p   # put the yank
dd  # delete a line
"0p # put the yank
```

For some more user friendly yanking & putting functionality you could use something like the [YankRing plugin](https://github.com/vim-scripts/YankRing.vim).  I suppose it might be possible to update YankRing to implement the kind of functionality you were looking for as well.

Answer (score 0):

So basically, you want to repeat `"_dd` without having to press `"_` again?

Just use `.`, which will repeat the entirety of the last edit sequence.  For example, this will delete both "Hello" lines into `_`:

```
/Hello
"_dd
N.
```

To answer the very first part of your question, `"_d$` (Delete to end of line, into black hole register) is perfectly valid, as is `"_d/foo<enter>`, which would be "Delete from the cursor to the beginning of the first occurence of 'foo', into the black hold register".