# Vim Clever Whitespace Deletion

Tags: vim, whitespace

Here was a similar post: [Vim, how to delete empty lines to "_ automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723299/vim-how-to-delete-empty-lines-to-automatically)

I didn't understand the accepted solution and found that it didn't work (at least not the way that I wanted).

I want it so that using `dd` on an empty line (whether in visual or normal mode) will automatically put the deleted whitespace lines into the black hole register without me having to explicitly invoke it by using `"_dd`

I understand that one can just map `"_dd` to some other key, but that is not what I'm asking here. Also, taking care of character deletions is rather straightforward: `nnormap x "_x`

One solution could be to

- re-direct the delete to the last register on the register stack (since this register is likely to never be used anyway) (`"9` for example)
- Then, check the value of `"9` to see if it is only whitespace
- If it is, then don't do anything
- Else, copy the value of `"9` into `""`

I think I know how to do all of my proposed solution other than the check to see if the register contains only whitespace part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not the most elegant solution, but here's what I came up with (with the help of @DJMcMayhem in a separate question I asked).

A function and binding for normal mode line deletion `dd`:

```
function! Smart_Delete_dd()
    let temp = getreg('"', 1)
    execute 'normal!' 'dd'
    if matchstr(@", '\_s*') == @"    " if just whitespace
        call setreg('"', temp)
    endif
endfunction
nnoremap <silent> dd :call Smart_Delete_dd()<CR>
```

A function and binding for visual mode line deletion `Vd`:

```
function! Smart_Delete_Vd() range
    let temp = getreg('"', 1)
    execute 'normal!' . (a:lastline - a:firstline + 1) . 'dd'
    if matchstr(@", '\_s*') == @"    " if just whitespace
        call setreg('"', temp)
    endif
endfunction
vnoremap <silent> d :call Smart_Delete_Vd()<CR>
```